# How to erase the number zero

Tags: java

I have two storage one for the positive elements and one for negative elements, and extracting the necessary logic that will perform the appropriate elements and placing them in the appropriate thread.

But I get the number of zeros that would be it be in the code.

```
int[] array= {12, 23, -22, 0, 43,545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};


   int[] negativni= new int[array.length];
   int[] pozitivni= new int[array.length];

    for (int x = 0, y=0; x <array.length; x++, y++) 
    {
       if (array[x]<0) {
              negativni[x]=array[x];
            }
        if (array[y]>-0) {
            pozitivni[y]=array[y];
         }
    }
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pozitivni));
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(negativni));
```

This outputs:

```
[12, 23, 0, 0, 43, 545, 0, 0, 43, 12, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, -22, 0, 0, 0, -4, -55, 0, 0, 0, -999, -87]
```

how can I improve my code?

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to exclude the zeros from your array of negative numbers?

Comment: What thread? What's wrong with your present code? What's the question?

Comment: Btw, `-0` and `0` are actually the same so from a readability point of view I'd replace `>-0` with `> 0`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing like this:

```
      int[] array= {12, 23, -22, 0, 43,545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};


       int[] negativni= new int[array.length];
       int[] pozitivni= new int[array.length];

       int x;
        for ( x = 0; x <array.length; x++) 
        {
           if (array[x]<0) {
                  negativni[x]=array[x];
                }
            else if (array[x]>0) {
                pozitivni[x]=array[x];
             }
        }
```

Adding a for loop to remove the zero from `negativni` array:

```
       int k=0;
        for( int i=0;  i<negativni.length;  i++ )
        {
            if (negativni[i] != 0)
                negativni[k++] = negativni[i];
        }
```

Adding a for loop to remove the zero from `pozitivni` array:

```
      int m=0;
      for( int i=0;  i<pozitivni.length;  i++ )
        {
          if (pozitivni[i] != 0)
              pozitivni[m++] = pozitivni[i];
        }
```

Adding two new array with `negative` and `positive` elements with new size

```
         int [] newArrayNegative = new int[m];
         int [] newArrayPositive = new int[k];
```

Here copy just not zero elements in new arrays

```
        System.arraycopy( pozitivni, 0, newArrayNegative, 0, m );
        System.arraycopy( negativni, 0, newArrayPositive, 0, k );
```

Print new arrays values

```
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArrayNegative));
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArrayPositive));
```

Output:

```
  [12, 23, 43, 545, 43, 12]
  [-22, -4, -55, -999, -87]
```

Answer (score 4):

You have some zeros because you initialize an array of 13 elements. So Java initialize the elements with the default value of an int, and it's `0`.

If you want a dynamic sized and ordered array, you have to use a `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

You should  not increment x and y unless you've added a negative or positive number respectively. Change the outer cycle to be over `i`(a separate variable) and only increment `y` and `x` in the if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a separate counter per sub array, and only increment this if you insert a value in the array.

```
int[] negativni= new int[array.length];
int[] pozitivni= new int[array.length];
int negativniLength = 0;
int pozitivniLength = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++) 
{
    if (array[i]<0) {
        negativni[negativniLength++]=array[i];
    }
    if (array[i]>-0) {
        pozitivni[pozitivniLength++]=array[i];
    }
}
```

Then you can make the arrays smaller using [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)).

```
pozitivni = Arrays.copyOf(pozitivni,pozitivniLength);
negativni = Arrays.copyOf(negativni,negativniLength);
```

Then print them out:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pozitivni));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(negativni));
```